# Insert the same text file inside several text files

Tags: sed, find

I would like to insert the content of a text file, let's call it Menu.incl inside several different files. I know how to do that on a single file, by using the sed command and by introducing a mark in the target file:

```
sed -e '/the Menu is Here/r Menu.incl' F.html > F_Menu.html
```

I want to keep the original file for possible future evolution of the Menu.incl file.

How could I do that for each member of a collection of html files ? My guess : with the find command? I tried to obtain the expected result with the following command:

```
find . -name '*.html' -exec sed -e '/the Menu is Here/r Menu.incl' '{}' +
```

but I don't know how to save each modified .html content inside a copy, i.e. without spoiling the original html files

Than you for your help,
Romuald

Answer (score 1):

Try with *process substitution*:

```
while read f; do
  d=$(dirname "$f")
  b=$(basename "$f")
  b="new.$b"
  sed -e '/the Menu is Here/ r Menu.incl' "$f" > "$d/$b"; 
done < <(find . -type f -iname "*.html" -print)
```

Comment: nice, thank you very much.Is there a possibility to create new.F.html instead of F.html.new ?

Comment: @user2997973: Simply change the output redirection as you want.

Comment: It is less obvious, since $f contains the relative pathway and not only the name of the html files, so that I get an erreor message when I redirect to "new$f" instead of "$f.new" ->> new./test.html

Comment: @user2997973: Ok. I didn't realise of it. I've updated the answer to use `dirname` and `basename` to split the path and edit the filename.

Comment: Thanks. I found another possibility, by taking advantage of the -printf option of the find command: while read f; do    sed -e '/the Menu is Here/ r Menu.incl' "$f" > "new.$f";  done < <(find . -type f -iname "*.html" -printf '%f/n')